# Why does border-radius only affect one corner?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a image have round corners yet whenever I use `border-radius : 6px` or `border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px` it only affects one corner making the rest "stale".

**HTML CODE**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./home.css" >
</head>
<body>
    <script src="home.js"></script>

    <div class="details">
        <div id="background">
            <img src="../util/images/patterns.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS CODE** :

```css
body {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
        width: 327px;
    height: 468.5px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10.5px;
    
}

.details #background{
    position: absolute;
    width: 327px;
    height: 468.5px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10.5px;
    
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #29A65D;
    background: #2DCC70;
    border-radius : 6px;
}
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your code into jsfiddle and got 4 rounded corners.  Can you create a jsfiddle and post it here with a link so we can see exactly what your issue is?

Comment: @elPastor I sent this to another comment but; 
 
Basically when I remove the overlay I get the scroll bar and once I scroll down I see the corners. EX;  ( https://gyazo.com/ee681c931ff4eff9195c7ec91c6ec389.mp4 ). So I'm guessing with overlay; hidden I cannot see the rest of the circles.

Comment: So all 4 corners are rounded, it's just an issue of the overlay window being smaller and thus needing to scroll to see the corners.

Comment: @elPastor, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it, so I'm guessing when I copied the code from figma seen here

```html
body {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 40px;
    width: 316px;
    height: 447px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10.5px;
}
```

and once I removed left and top it fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

you were laying the img over the div.  Try this.

```css
body {
    
    
    overflow: hidden;
        width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background:pink;
   
    
}

.details #background{
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 10.5px;
    background:green;
    
    
}

img{
position:absolute;
left:10px;
top:10px;
border-radius:15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./home.css" >
</head>
<body>
    <script src="home.js"></script>

    <div class="details">
        <div id="background">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sadly that wasn't the answer, I did find it out do but now I need to solve it. When I do overlay : hidden, it hides the rest of the border-radius aswell.

Comment: sadly, your comment makes no sense. can you rewrite in coherent sentences? What exactly is the problem?  The img now has rounded corners which is what you asked for.

Comment: So basically when I remove the overlay I get the scroll bar and once I scroll down I see the corners. EX;  ( https://gyazo.com/ee681c931ff4eff9195c7ec91c6ec389.mp4 ). So I'm guessing with overlay; hidden I cannot see the rest of the circles.